# Why increasing the coefficient of friction results in evenly distributed load in rolling machines?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, steel, friction, rolling

I'm designing a rolling machine for reduction of steel ingots of $5 mm$ to $1.96 mm$ thick. I can convince myself using equations why increasing the coefficient of friction (in case of lubrication system fails) results in evenly distributed load in rolling machines, but i can't describe intuitively why this happens. [image]

As the friction coefficient increase, normal forces increase as wel and i expect the peak to move upward, but why it moves to the right as well ?

The horizontal axis, represents the angle of contact zone, and the vertical axis shows the dimensionless stress. $\frac{\theta}{\theta_0} = 0$ means exit angle(reduced) and $\frac{\theta}{\theta_0} = 1$ means entry angle.

Comment: Could it be that with the increase in friction, your increasing some form of deflection in the machine, resulting in a change of angle?

Comment: @Corey, interesting idea, indeed, increasing the normal force results in deflection of the slab and it increases the contact surface.